# NSURL relativeToURL backwards?

Tags: swift, nsurl

My NSURLs are being formatted backwards, even when copying and pasting in code from other projects which makes zero sense.

For example:

```
let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/v1/")
NSURL(string: "foo", relativeToURL: baseURL)
```

Should return: "http://example.com/v1/foo"

Instead returns:  "foo -- ttp://example.com/v1/"

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply how relative URLs are displayed in their (debug) description. The `absoluteString` will still be correct; this format is unrelated.

```
let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/v1/")!
let u = NSURL(string: "foo", relativeToURL: baseURL)!

print(u)  // prints the URL's description, "foo -- http://example.com/v1/"
print(u.absoluteString)  // prints "http://example.com/v1/foo"
```